# Oracle SQL Alias usage

Tags: sql, oracle, alias

I have defined an alias:

```
concat(lower(DBO.tname.fname),lower(dbo.tname.lname)) as TNAME,
```

and later on want to use TNAME in a regex expression:

```
REGEXP_LIKE (TNAME,'smith')
```

This fails with the error:

```
ORA-00904: "TNAME": invalid indentifier
```

however if I substitute TNAME with the original expression everything is fine:

```
REGEXP_LIKE (concat(lower(DBO.tname.fname),lower(dbo.tname.lname)),'smith')
```

How else, may I replace a complex expression, if not by using an alias?

Many thanks, for the help.

Comment: Use a subquery or CTE.

Comment: Unless you reference it in outer query, it won't recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

The order of operation is
`FROM`,
`WHERE,`
`SELECT`,
`ORDER BY`
You put your alias in SELECT.  If you your comparison `REGEXP_LIKE (TNAME,'smith')` in WHERE clause, it won't recognize it.

```
SELECT TNAME
FROM (
    SELECT concat(lower(DBO.tname.fname),lower(dbo.tname.lname)) as TNAME, some_other_cols
    FROM some_table
)
```